# How to roll a 2d square sprite in forward and backward?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am currently making a 2d game where I want my 2d square to move forward and backward by rolling it into that direction.
I have no idea how to do that.

I tried many methods including RotateAround  and tried many Youtube tutorials(which were mostly for a 3d cube) by applying it to my project but none of them worked...

Answer (score 0):

Utilize Rigidbody.AddTorque() for instance:

```cs
public Rigidbody2D rotatingCubeRigidbody;
public float rotatingSpeed = 5;
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
    {
        //Rotate Right
        rotatingCubeRigidbody.AddTorque(-1 * rotatingSpeed);  
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
    {
        //Rotate Left
        rotatingCubeRigidbody.AddTorque(rotatingSpeed);
    }
}
```

The cube will rotate counterclockwise and move to the left with a positive value and rotate clockwise and move to the right with a negative value.